# Check a column in all worksheets and see if it matches the input sheet vba and call a new macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 key sheets Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. From Sheet 2 - column B, Based on the unique values, multiple new worksheets are created with the sheet names based on the column values(For this the code is done)
For all the newly created sheets

1. Insert 2 new rows and in S2 and R3 provide values
2. Also i need to check for a date provided by user in D2 of Sheet 1 against all the dates in the newly created worksheets in column I
3. If the date matches, call macro 10 if not display an error saying date mismatch in "worksheet Name". Do you still want to run macro 10. If user says yes run macro 10 if not end sub

I have started the code as below but am stuck for point 2 and 3

```
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
    With ws
    .Rows("1:2").Insert
    .Range ("S2") = "OB"
    .Range ("R3") = "AD"
```

Can anyone help me how i can proceed with this please

Answer (score 0):

you could build on this

```
Option Explicit

Sub HelpHer()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    With ActiveWorkbook
    
        Dim refDate As Date
            refDate = .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value
            
            For Each ws In .Worksheets
            
                Select Case ws.Name
                    Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
                    
                    Case Else

                        With ws
                        
                            .Rows("1:2").Insert
                            .Range("S2") = "OB"
                            .Range("R3") = "AD"
                            
                            Dim foundCel As Range
                                Set foundCel = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("I:I")).Find(what:=refDate, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                                
                                Dim okRun As Boolean
                                    Select Case True
                                        Case Not foundCel Is Nothing
                                            okRun = True
                                            
                                        Case MsgBox("date mismatch in sheet '" & .Name & "'" _
                                                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you still want to run macro 10?", _
                                                    vbYesNo) = vbYes
                                            okRun = True
                                            
                                        Case Else
                                            okRun = False
                                    End Select
                                          
                                        If okRun Then
                                            'run your macro
                                        End If
                                                        
                        End With
                
                End Select
            
            Next
        
    End With
        

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sDate, c As Range
    Dim bMatch As Boolean, sMsg As String
    Const KEY_COL = "I"
    Const START_ROW = 2 ' Modify as needed, the first date in colum I
    sDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
            bMatch = True
            With ws
                .Rows("1:2").Insert
                .Range("S2") = "OB"
                .Range("R3") = "AD"
                For Each c In .Range(.Cells(START_ROW, KEY_COL), .Cells(.Rows.Count, KEY_COL).End(xlUp))
                    If Not c.Value = sDate Then
                        bMatch = False
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                If bMatch Then
                    Call Macro10
                Else
                    sMsg = "Date mismatch in " & .Name & "." & _
                        vbNewLine & "Do you still want to run macro 10?"
                    If MsgBox(sMsg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then Call Macro10
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```